# "wrong number or types of arguments in call" when inserting rows? PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

So I'm trying to call a procedure I have made. The procedure was made successfully, however, when I try to insert values it tells me I do not have the right amount of parameters.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_employee
(
    p_employeeid            IN employees.employeeid%TYPE,
    p_employeename          IN employees.employeename%TYPE,
    p_phone                 IN employees.phone%TYPE,
    p_jobid                 IN employees.jobid%TYPE,
    p_salary                IN employees.salary%TYPE,
    p_managerid             IN employees.managerid%TYPE,
    p_departmentid          IN employees.departmentid%TYPE,
    jobid_cnt       OUT INTEGER,
    deptid_cnt      OUT INTEGER,
    empid_cnt           OUT INTEGER
)

AS
BEGIN
    IF p_employeeid   IS NULL OR
       p_employeename IS NULL OR
       p_jobid        IS NULL OR
       p_salary < 0 
    THEN
       RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
    END IF;
    SELECT count(*)
        INTO jobid_cnt
        FROM employees e
        WHERE e.jobid = p_jobid;

    IF jobid_cnt = 0 THEN     -- there's no such job in the table
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
    END IF;

    SELECT count(*)
        INTO deptid_cnt
        FROM employees e
        WHERE e.departmentid = p_departmentid;

    IF deptid_cnt = 0 THEN     -- there's no such department in the table
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
    END IF;

    SELECT count(*)
        INTO empid_cnt
        FROM employees e
        WHERE e.employeeid = p_employeeid;

    IF deptid_cnt > 0 THEN     -- employee already exists within table
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Employee already exists');
    END IF;

    COMMIT;
END;
/


CALL insert_employee(109, 'Jack', '416 123 4567', 'FI_ACCOUNT', 7890.00, 104, 30);
```

I would expect that the OUT parameters are different than the IN parameters, but I could be wrong. The error becomes "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to INSERT_EMPLOYEE" Thank you

Comment: You've defined the procedure as taking 10 arguments, but you're only providing seven.

Comment: How would I declare the extra 3 in the procedure?

Answer (score 4):

*You need to declare the out parameters and execute the procedure*

```
declare
    jobid_cnt        INTEGER;
    deptid_cnt      INTEGER ;
    empid_cnt            INTEGER;
begin 
   insert_employee(109, 'Jack', '416 123 4567', 'FI_ACCOUNT', 7890.00, 104, 30,jobid_cnt,deptid_cnt,empid_cnt);
    dbms_output.put_line(jobid_cnt);
    dbms_output.put_line(deptid_cnt);
    dbms_output.put_line(empid_cnt);
Commit;
end;
```

Comment: You cannot use `Call` within a block so removed it.